# Read a list from stream using Yap-Prolog

Tags: stream, prolog, pipe, yap

I want to run a (python3) process from my (yap) prolog script and read its output formatted as a list of integers, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

This is what I do:

```
process_create(path(python3),
    ['my_script.py', MyParam],
    [stdout(pipe(Out))]),
read(Out, OutputList),
close(Out).
```

However, it fails at *read/2* predicate with the error:

```
PL_unify_term: PL_int64 not supported
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I am sure that I can run the process correctly because with `[stdout(std)]` parameter given to `process_create` the program outputs `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` as expected.

Weird thing is that when I change the process to output some constant term (as `constant_term`) it still gives the same `PL_int64` error. Appending a dot to the process' output (`[1,2,3,4,5,6].`) doesn't solve the error. Using `read_term/3` gives the same error. `read_string/3` is undefined in YAP-Prolog.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking at the yap-users mailing list I got [the solution](https://sourceforge.net/p/yap/mailman/message/35752525/).

Re-compiled YAP Prolog 6.2.2 with libGMP option and now it works. It may also occur in 32-bit YAP.